# Why would an auto layout constraint be activated without setActive: being called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have a constraint in my app that I programmatically set to be inactive. However, when I pause the app shortly after setting it inactive, the debugger shows that it is active. If I set a breakpoint on `-[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]` I find that after setting the constraint to inactive, it is never called again for that constraint. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that after deactivating the constraint the reference to it is still valid (weak referenced constraints may be deallocated if set to inactive since they are removed from the view), and remember to call `layoutIfNeeded()` after adding and removing constraints.

Comment: You usually don’t need to call layoutIfNeeded() after modifying constraints.

Comment: @Sven My phrasing was ambiguous, by modifying, i meant adding and removing constraints, edited for clarity.